# How to host apache roller on a shared apache tomcat server

Tags: apache, blogs, apache-roller

Finally I am ready with my roller with my faded java knowledge. Thanks to the Apache roller which made the daunting task so easy and Gelen for answering my stupid questions with patience.

Now I have a new problem of hosting this in a shared apache server where they don't allow any changes to be made in their lib directory.

Any workaround is there as I am not able to place roller.custom.properties and other jar files in lib directory of tomcat.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the roller-custom.properties overrides any values placed in the roller.properties file within the WAR.  If you can't create a roller-custom.properties file, you can just directly edit the roller.properties file.  But that's not a clean way to configure things.

Now as for the JARs, hmmm.  Roller may not be able to work in that environment.  Mail and DB connections are ordinarily configured in the Catalina server.xml so the mail and DB JARs would need to be in the Tomcat lib folder.  Maybe a Tomcat user's mailing list or a question for your ISP on a solution.

Per its documentation, Roller requires a servlet container where you can add things to the lib.  You may need to look at another hosting provider if your present one isn't allowing you to do that, or use another blogging software product.